# Why does casting a SQL MAX(DateTime) command work in SSMS but not in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, casting

The following query works as expected in MSSSMS version 18.1 on an Azure hosted SQL database table:

```sql
select Name, cast(MAX(DTStamp) as Datetime) AS Last_Seen FROM dbo.MyTable GROUP BY Name
```

Example output:

```
Fairyflosser29   2021-11-11 19:26:00.323
GoofballAnticz   2021-11-25 14:43:57.443
WeirdAlJankyVic  2021-12-01 19:30:20.341
```

However, the same SQL command in C# run through the following methods always cuts the milliseconds from the DateTime field, despite the cast and despite the way I write the cast. This is critical for me as my follow-up queries depend on the accuracy of the DateTime field being correct to the millisecond, otherwise the subsequent queries return nothing.

The process calls `GetLastSeenList()` which returns a comma-delimited list of records that represent the most recent (by date time stamp) records for each `Name` in the table. With the populated list, another method is called later on that uses these results to pull the full row for each item.

Because the datetime stamps include milliseconds, those subsequent queries must include the millisecond values otherwise the query fails even though there is a record.

First, get the list of names and when they were last seen. Next, pull the full row for each record in the last-seen list (not included here as the first query is not providing date-times as they are in the table - with milliseconds intact).

I'm not very adept with SQL, so please help me understand what I'm missing here.

- **Notes**

  1: The `DTStamp` column is defined as `datetime`

  2: I've tried the cast inside and out, going to ridiculous lengths like: `cast(MAX(cast(GPS_DTStamp as Datetime)) as Datetime) ...`

**[EDIT]:** Just in case it's not clear, the sql command  `sqlcmd_GetLastSeenList` is the same as the SSMS query at the top:

```cs
private static readonly string sqlcmd_GetLastSeenList =
  @"select Name, cast(MAX(DTStamp) as Datetime) AS Last_Seen FROM dbo.MyTable GROUP BY Name;";
```

GetLastSeen:

```cs
internal static async Task<string> GetLastSeenList()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var list = await ReadSQL(sqlcmd_GetLastSeenList, false);

    if(list != null && list.Count > 0)
    {
        // Just return a CSV list of ID's with last seen timestamps
        foreach(var record in list)
            sb.Append($"{record[0]} {record[1]},");
    }

    return sb.ToString().Trim(',');
}
```

ReadSQL:

```cs
private static async Task<List<object[]>> ReadSQL(string cmdText, bool isProd)
{
    List<object[]> response = new List<object[]>();
    string connect = string.Empty;

    if (isProd)
        connect = await SetConnectionProd(_uidProd, _p_pwd);
    else
        connect = await SetConnectionTest(_uidTest, _t_pwd);

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                response = await ExecuteQuery2(cmd, conn);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: log it
        throw ex;
    }

    return response;
}
```

ExecuteQuery2:

```cs
private static async Task<List<object[]>> ExecuteQuery2(SqlCommand cmd, SqlConnection conn)
{
    List<object[]> retval = new List<object[]>();

    try
    {
        object[] myVals = new object[MAXCOLUMNCOUNT];
        object[] myRow = null;
        
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(sqlreader.HasRows)
            {
                while(sqlreader.Read())
                {
                    var count = sqlreader.GetValues(myVals);
                    myRow = new object[count];
                    Array.Copy(myVals, myRow, count);

                    retval.Add(myRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Side point: `datetime` is only accurate to 1/3rd of a second, you probably want `datetime2`. Also you don't need `if(sqlreader.HasRows)` because `while(sqlreader.Read())` tells you that anyway. And `catch... throw ex;` is just wrong, it will wipe the stack trace

Comment: Give an example of a follow up query please; I want to check whether there's an all round better way of doing what you're doing (highly suspect the answer is "yes")

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I am still learning even at 60. I've rarely ever dealt with databases so this really is a new journey. The catch-throw, much like the table, fields and methods were sanitized and simplified for the question - no need to clutter it up with the even worse stuff in there, ha.  ;-)

Comment: Caius - Oh I'm sure there's a lot better and more elegant ways than my coke-glassed, ham-fisted means. Ultimately, I don't know SQL at all - so one of the things I'm doing is trying to get back the last time this user was active, but with the full row of data and not just their name and most recent activity date-time stamp.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need window functions, `ROW_NUMBER()` may be a lot simpler than what you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The miliseconds are there.  They're just not displayed by default by DateTime.ToString().  EG:

```
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("select cast('2021-11-11 19:26:00.323' as datetime) d", con);
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        rdr.Read();

        var vals = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
        rdr.GetValues(vals);

        var val = (DateTime)vals[0];

        Console.WriteLine($"{val.GetType().Name}   {val}   {val.ToString("O")}");
    }
```

outputs

```
DateTime   11/11/2021 7:26:00 PM   2021-11-11T19:26:00.3230000
```

But also make sure you're not converting back and forth between `datetime` and `datetime2`, eg this

```
select cast(cast('2021-11-11 19:26:00.323' as datetime) as datetime2) d
```

outputs

```
d
---------------------------
2021-11-11 19:26:00.3233333
```

and this kind of conversion can be the source of mis-compares on subesquent queries.

Comment: Browne  - the central problem was indeed the default hiding of the milliseconds.  As my reader method is used for other queries, when I pop rows into a string as an object, it uses the default .ToString(). Thank you!